# Manipulating Output From Fortify Audit Workbench

Tags: source-code

I have an output from a Fortify SCA Scan and I am viewing it in the Audit Workbench. I am looking for a way to list out the file paths and line numbers of vulnerabilities found. For e.g., if the category 'System Information Leak' has 200 occurrences, then I am trying to output the file paths and line numbers where these 200 occurrences are present. The only way to do this at present looks like manually right clicking on each file to copy the file path and entering the corresponding line number manually.

Any ideas on how to automate this task? I could not find any file that stores the output seen in the GUI. That could be one starting point. If anyone can suggest something, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a question for the vendor.

Comment: Hi schroeder, sorry for the late reply. You are right, I am currently trying to work out a solution with HP for this. Will post the solution once it gets finalized. Thanks.